# Can not query tables in Cosmos Fi-Lab Global Instance from PHP

Tags: php, hadoop, fiware, filab

I've implemented a PHP script following [this documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient) and i correctly listed the stored databases; unfortunately i can not query any of the tables, receiving this error:

```
[message:protected] => HiveExecuteException: Execute Error:: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from shark.execution.SparkTask query:: select * from HIVE_TABLE_NAME
```

But in Hive CLI the query shows the results properly.

Waiting for your feedback, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unexpectedly today the problem is gone.

Thank you.

Comment: The HDFS of the global instance automatically entered in safe mode due it was close to 100% usage. After freeing some space in the cluster, it is up again. Sorry for the inconveniences.